# Delphi ITE: when can resource IDs change?

Tags: delphi, translation, resources

I'm looking into Delphi ITE ([Integrated Translation Environment](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Localizing_Applications_by_Using_Translation_Manager_Index)) to add multi-language support in my app. I'm concerned about validity issues for resource DLLs, which is generated by ITE. In other words, when it is safe to deploy already compiled resource DLL, if main application was recompiled or (possibly) changed.

Questions:

- **If I just rebuild main/host project multiply times *without changing*** - can IDs of strings change? Will I need to invoke "Update localized projects"?
- **If I *change* (and recompile) main project, but *without changing resourcestrings and DFMs*** - can IDs of strings change? Will I need to invoke "Update localized projects"?
- **If I change main project by *adding or removing resourcestrings and/or DFMs*** - can IDs of strings change? Will I need to invoke "Update localized projects"?

Main reason for this question is that I want to know if it is safe to ship old translations with new updated version of my software. It would be really painfull to keep zillions of versions of resource DLLs for each version of software.

Second reason for this question: it seems that there is a bug in Delphi ITE, as highlighted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013312/delphi-compile-and-build-produce-different-binary-on-same-project).

Comment: Could you add a link, for the benefit of those of us unfamiliar with ITE?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, yes, they can change more often then you would like. I guess it could depends on which units gets recompiled and in which order, or something alike. IIRC, two recompilation may not lead to exactly the same executable as well. I got the habit to update the resource DLLs everytime I need to deploy them with a new executable.

Comment: That is also my experience, but I hoped someone would tell me better.

Comment: I suspect that too, but, actually, I was hoping for some official responce from developers :D Since help doesn't highlight this question, so we all can only guess here. No reliable info.

Comment: The ITE has been unluckily often overlooked since it was introduced. I'd recommend to open a Quality Central bug/enhancement request.

Comment: I've 0 expierence in ITE, so I'm not sure what to write yet. Does anybody who actually used it reported some issues?

Comment: I've reported some issues about it, yes. Anyway the question you linked was answered by Delphi chief scientist, and thereby that's a "definitive" one. If units can be linked in a different order, I believe resource IDs can be generated in a different order as well.